# Undesired result in csv upload in shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, csv

I'm using the below  script for a csv upload into my **DB**

```
for _csv_file in ${_csv_files[@]}
do
mysql -h $_host -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db --local_infile=1 -e "use $_db" -e"
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$_csv_file'
IGNORE INTO TABLE csv_temp_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'  
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(\`ProductType\`, 
\`Title\`, 
\`Publisher\`, 
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .  
\`Hi_Res_Image\` 
);"
 done  
 exit;
```

But what happens is, instead of **63** lines in csv,I get **632** lines inserted into my database!
what am I doing wrong here? Please Help me. Thanks!

**sample csv**

```
ProductType|Title|Publisher|Navarre Publisher NBR|Platform-Format|Artist|Genre|Theme|Material Group|Box Size|Height(in)|Width(in)|Length(in)|Weight(lb)|CaseHeight(in)|CaseWidth(in)|CaseLength(in)|CaseWeight(lb)|Rating|UPC|Navarre P/N|Mfg P/N|Release Date|MSRP|Description|Lo_Res_Image|Hi_Res_Image
ACCESSORIES|VERSACHECK FORM  1000 BLUE PRESTIGE 500|GLOBAL BIZ FORCE|GBF|APP-BASED ACCESSORY||213|0|ACC-095|LG|2.800|8.900|11.400|6.600|9.300|11.900|13.100|27.400|E|814329506231|8026727|10BP02-6231|08/12/2008|$36.99|VersaCheck® - Form #1000 Business Voucher Check Refills are the perfect 
high-security blank check paper designed specifically to use with all VersaCheck® software products (except personal versions) to print custom business checks that comply 100% with ANSI X9 banking standards. 
 Save 50-80% or more per pack vs. pre-printed mail order checks.<br /><br />This
```

Comment: I'm not a mysql user but the `IGNORE 1 LINES` seems not to be complete regarding the sample cvs you provide: it's missing `"Navarre Publisher NBR|Platform-Format"`...

Comment: @prodev_paris  `IGNORE 1 LINES` is used for removing the headers,It has nothing to do with problem I've.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be line breaks in your csv. I assume your sample csv should just contain one entry (below the header) - with a long description and no Lo_Res_Image or Hi_Res_Image.

But the description includes two line breaks so you'd end up with three lines in your database when you'd expect one.